# Javascript change h1 text

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text of `h1` via using following code

```
document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap").getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'Application Forms';
```

Here is the `HTML` code

```html
<div id="wpbody-content">
  
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </div>

<div class="clear"></div></div>
```

But it shows me following error

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementsByClassName(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

Answer (score 5):

the `getElementsByClassName()` method returns an array of elements.  You need to refer to the first wrap element in the array, just like you are correctly doing for the h1 elements.:

```
document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'Application Forms';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getElementsByClassName("wrap")` by `getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0]`

```js
    document.getElementById("wpbody-content")
        .getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0]
        .getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'Application Forms';
```

```html
<div id="wpbody-content">
    <div class="wrap">
         <h1>Text</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use getElementsByTagName:

```js
document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'Application Forms';
```

```html
<div id="wpbody-content">
    <div class="wrap">
         <h1>Text</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

try jQuery as

```
     $('#wpbody-content .wrap h1').text('Application Forms');
```